# JUnit 5: What does "Assertion messages can be lazily evaluated" mean?

Tags: lambda, junit, junit5, junit-jupiter

About JUnit 5 documentation in the [2.5. Assertions](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-assertions) section, exists the following `@Test` method

```
@Test
void standardAssertions() {
    assertEquals(2, calculator.add(1, 1));
    assertEquals(4, calculator.multiply(2, 2),
            "The optional failure message is now the last parameter");
    assertTrue('a' < 'b', () -> "Assertion messages can be lazily evaluated -- "
            + "to avoid constructing complex messages unnecessarily.");
}
```

Is not clear what is the advantage to use `() -> "Assertion messages can be lazily evaluated -- ..."` and not simply `"Assertion messages can be lazily evaluated -- ..."` It means: `() -> ""` vs `""`

Therefore:

```
    assertTrue('a' < 'b', () -> "Assertion messages can be lazily evaluated -- "
            + "to avoid constructing complex messages unnecessarily.");
    assertTrue('a' < 'b', "Assertion messages can be lazily evaluated -- "
            + "to avoid constructing complex messages unnecessarily.");
```

What does *Assertion messages can be lazily evaluated* mean?

Some example(s) is/are appreciate. I want to know when would be mandatory use the *lambda* approach. The current official documentation does not cover this explicitly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the situation when part of the assertion message comes from a database field (or through a web request). Without lazy evaluation the database will be queried even if the assertion succeeds. Hiding message text creation behind a lambda gives you the chance to run expensive code only if it is really needed.